# Multiple users of RStudio on virtual machine gives fatal error

Tags: r, rstudio

We use an installation of RStudio on a virtual machine, accessible by multiple users. With version 0.98.501 this was no problem. Lately we installed version  0.99.447 and now RStudio gives an error as soon as somenone tries to open RStudio as a second user. Also we changed R version from 3.1.1 to 3.2.1, but this doesn't seem to cause the problem because opening of R without RStudio by multiple users is still possible.

This is the error:

[image]

Has anyone an idea what's going wrong here? Many thanks in advance!

*EDIT* The dutch error message says something like: "the path to the storage place(?) is invalid".

Comment: Can you translate the error message?

Comment: I added a translation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known issue with RStudio 0.99, and was fixed in build 0.99.451. The latest build (0.99.465) has the fix; you can get it here:

https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/

Comment: Thanks! This was indeed the case.